# Angular CDK: How to create a drag and drop list with parent and child elements

Tags: javascript, html, angular, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I'm trying to implement a drag and drop list in Angular using the Angular CDK. The list should have parent and child elements, and I want to enable the ability to drag and drop both parent items and their child items. Additionally, I need to allow dragging child items within their respective parent container.

I have already set up the basic structure of the list and implemented the drag and drop functionality, but I'm facing issues with dragging child items between parent container. When I try to drag and drop the child between different parents I am not able to do that. How can I acheive this?

Below is the stackblitz link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dragdrop-from-parent-to-nested-childlist-p943w3?file=app%2Fcdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.html,app%2Fcdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.css,app%2Fcdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.ts

Here's my current implementation:

```
<div cdkDropListGroup>
  <ul
    cdkDropList
    [cdkDropListData]="parent"
    [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="parentIds"
    class="example-list"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
  >
    <li *ngFor="let item of parent" cdkDrag [cdkDragData]="parent">
      {{item.name}}
      <ul
        #childList="cdkDropList"
        *ngIf="item.children"
        [cdkDropListData]="item.children"
        cdkDropList
        [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[parent1]"
        (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
      >
        <li
          *ngFor="let subItem of item.children"
          cdkDrag
          [cdkDragData]="item.name"
        >
          {{subItem.name}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

component.ts

```
  parentList: any[] = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Parent 1', children: [{ id: 11, name: 'Child 1' }, { id: 12, name: 'Child 2' }] },
    { id: 2, name: 'Parent 2', children: [{ id: 21, name: 'Child 3' }, { id: 22, name: 'Child 4' }] }
  ];

  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<any[]>) {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(
        event.previousContainer.data,
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex
      );
    }
  }
}
```

ave also applied CSS styles to ensure proper visual representation of the parent and child items.

I would appreciate any guidance on how to correctly implement the drag and drop functionality for the child items within the parent container. What changes do I need to make to my code to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by removing the `[cdkDropListConnectedTo]="parentIds"` in the template.

Comment: I tried that as well,, but not working. Have you checked the stakblitz demo?